# How to make solver parameters as variable

Tags: vba

Function: To solve a solver problems on part one of the worksheet (within A1:N280), then move on to solve the same solver problem (with slightly different parameter values) fifteen columns to the right (i.e. O1:AB280), up til a total of 60 segments. These segments all have similar formatting.

```
Sub SolverAutomator()

Dim i, k As Integer
Dim var1, var1a As Range
Dim from1, from1a As Range
Dim to1, to1a As Range
Dim sum1, sum1a As Range

For i = 0 To 60

k = i * 15

Set var1 = Range("$M$151")
Set var1a = var1.Offset(0, k)
Set from1 = Range("$M$140")
Set from1a = from1.Offset(0, k)
Set to1 = Range("$M$149")
Set to1a = to1.Offset(0, k)
Set sum1 = Range("$N$149")
Set sum1a = sum1.Offset(0, k)

SolverReset
SolverOK setCell:="var1a", maxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, byChange:="from1a: to1a" _
, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd cellRef:=sum1a, relation:=2, formulaText:="1"
SolverSolve
SolverSolve userFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i
End Sub
```

I apologise for the horrible coding.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying do do with this horrendous code.  Whatever it is, there's probably a better way!

Comment: No seriously I have no idea what this is supposed to be, so I have no advice for you. May I suggested [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from [so]'s top user.

Comment: I am trying to automate the solver process on a sheet with 60 similar solver questions side by side. Each question is 14 columns long. Meaning: after solving the question in col A to N, it will start solving the question in col O to AB, and so on. So the solver will move 15 columns to the right everytime it solves one question, so that it can solve the next. That's why I added the offset(0,k) to the Range variable.

Comment: How often is this sheet going to have the another set of questions?  Or is this a one-time thing?  By the time you figure out the code it could have be done the "proper way".  Could you share a sample question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but I'd do something like this:

```
For i = 0 To 60

    k = i * 15

    SolverReset

    SolverOK setCell:=Range("M151").Offset(0, k), _
             maxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
             byChange:=Range("M140:M149").Offset(0, k), _
             Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

    SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("N149").Offset(0, k), _
              relation:=2, formulaText:="1"

    SolverSolve
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i
```

Comment: Yes, it works! This is what I have been looking for! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @AnswerMe If the answer solved your problem, please accept it. It's always nice to say Thank you but that's not how SO works.